# Creating a mixin with possibility to add something to it in LESS

Tags: less

I'm trying to create a mixin that will create a possibility to make category-depenedant colors in wordpress in no-time. It doesn't work, though. When I create try to make a .category-foo(#000000){} line in my style, it either isn't converted to .css or it does nothing. However, when I change the .category(...){} to .category-foo it STILL does not work when it's declared as .category-foo in the main style.
I'm asking now, is it even possible to create such a mixin in LESS that will allow me to add bonus variables depending on category name? Like .category-a(black), .category-b(white). That would really be a blessing for me.

```
.category(@catcolor : @white){
    h2{color: @catcolor;}
        a, .foo p, .foo a{color:@catcolor;
            &:hover,&:active{color:lighten(@catcolor, 10%);}
        }
        img{.transition(background-color 0.8s ease-out);
            &:hover,&:active{background-color:@catcolor;}
        }
        .featured-image{.transition(background-color 0.8s ease-out);
            &:hover,&:active{background-color:@catcolor;}
        }
        ::-moz-selection{background-color:@catcolor; color:@white;}
        ::selection{background-color:@catcolor; color:@white;}
```

}

Comment: Can you edit your post and put a small sample of what exactly you are expecting your generated css to look like. I'm a little unclear if you expect the `.category-a` and `.category-b` to be a parent selector to the nested selectors under it, or if you are just using those as mixin names to generate different code.

Comment: Well, I want to create a mixin that will allow me to add a category name AFTER the `-` sign. I can't figure it out if it's even possible to create something that will allow me to do things like `.category-blue(#fff){} .category-red(#000){} ` to set styling just to these categories, without any other parent or children elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still seems like there may be two possibilities of what you are going for.

### #1 Parent Category Selector

If I understand your comment correctly, you want to be able to add a category name to a selector that will also style the css within it based on that category class. If so, this is a reduced sample of your example:

**LESS**

```
//mixin defined
.category(@catName: a, @catColor: white) {

  //add category name to selector
  .category-@{catName} {
    h2 {color: @catColor;}
    a, .bar p, .bar a{color:@catColor;
            &:hover,&:active{color:lighten(@catColor, 10%);}
        }
  }
}

//call it
.category(foo, blue);
```

**CSS Output**

```
.category-foo h2 {
  color: #0000ff;
}
.category-foo a,
.category-foo .bar p,
.category-foo .bar a {
  color: #0000ff;
}
.category-foo a:hover,
.category-foo .bar p:hover,
.category-foo .bar a:hover,
.category-foo a:active,
.category-foo .bar p:active,
.category-foo .bar a:active {
  color: #3333ff;
}
```

### #2 Category Specific Mixin CSS Generator

Perhaps you do not want an actual category class as your parent selector, but simply want to generate code based off a particular category name (perhaps even having that name be a class all of itself). If so, something like this nested mixin would work:

**LESS**

```
.category(@catName: a, @catColor: white) {

  //This is common code used by all categories
  //It has an example of using the category name to generate a class name
  .categoryCommonCode() {
    h2 {color: @catColor;}
    a, .@{catName} p, .@{catName}  a {color:@catColor;
            &:hover,&:active{color:lighten(@catColor, 10%);}
        }
  }

  //set up guarded mixins
  .category(foo) {
    .categoryCommonCode();
  .specialFooOnlyClass {color: darken(@catColor, 20%);}
  }

  .category(bar) {
    .categoryCommonCode();
    .specialBarOnlyClass {color: darken(@catColor, 50%);}
  }

  //Call the appropriate nested mixin
  .category(@catName);
}

//Call it
.category(foo, blue);
```

**CSS Output**

```
h2 {
  color: #0000ff;
}
a,
.foo p,
.foo a {
  color: #0000ff;
}
a:hover,
.foo p:hover,
.foo a:hover,
a:active,
.foo p:active,
.foo a:active {
  color: #3333ff;
}
.specialFooOnlyClass {
  color: #000099;
}
```

Comment: Hell, that's totally what I wanted. Thanks a lot. :)